# Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I have two projects: one is MVC4 application and another is output type class library.

I want to make the second project (the class library one) an insights communication layer.

The code compiles and the server runs normally.

```
public static void SaveMetric(string title, double value, 
    string azureKey, Dictionary<string, string> properties = null)
{
    try
    {
        TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
        telemetry.InstrumentationKey = azureKey;
        telemetry.TrackMetric(title, value, properties);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        var a = "";
    }
}
```

The problem start's when I call the `telemetry.TrackMetric` function. This code returns the error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."(System.NullReferenceException).

Is it possible to use Microsoft Insights in a class library project? And if it is, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is some additional information need, does it say what is null? Is `title` or `properties` null? Certainly seems like `properties` could be since its a default parameter. What is it complaining about specifically? I know its marked as default in the metric method, but I can't find out if by default its null or an empty collection.

Comment: Ron Reyer, thaks in advance to try to solve this problem. See my edit for more information, and if you still have doubts, ask again.

Comment: @RicardoRocha - If you solved your problem, you should post your solution as an answer.  If this led you to a new question, you should ask your new question as a new SO question.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Philip Pittle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going deep in my search for solutions, I discovered that the problem was the update that I did (version 1.0 to 1.2). The solution was to downgrade the software to v1.0.

Comment: I'm new at this community. I just follow the advice of this comment  "If you solved your problem, you should post your solution as an answer. If this led you to a new question, you should ask your new question as a new SO question" by @Philip Pittle

Comment: This is a solution (you should self-accept once enough time has passed to do so).

Comment: Any idea why that solved it? I had the same problem with version 1.0.0 and tried upgrading TO 1.2.0 to solve my problem but so far no dice.

Comment: I understand you Dan. Maybe its better ask to azure team why this problem is happening

Answer (score 2):

I recently upgraded to 1.2.0 and ran into the same problem.  In addition to the standard setup, my code was overriding the instrumentation key in the `ApplicationInsights.config` with one stored in the `web.config`. This was done via the `global.asax - Application_Start`. The code works fine locally, but bombs out when deployed to Azure.

It turns out it was a problem of how I was accessing the `web.config`. I had to switch my code from using `WebConfigurationManager` to `ConfigurationManager`.

This `Application_Start` code:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyInstrumentationKey"];
```

changed to this:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyInstrumentationKey"];
```